# Dotted Line Detection CV2 Python

Tags: python, line, opencv

I'm trying to get rid of dotted lines and full lines in an image using some transformations but I'm only able to remove some of them using morph transformations and hough lines detections.

Here is an example: I need to remove the dotted lines and the long vertical lines while not affecting anything else.

Gray image input:

[image: Gray image input]

Here is my code so far:

```
thresh = cv2.threshold(num_bloc, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Remove vertical
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(num_bloc, [c], -1, (255,255,255), 2)

edges = cv2.Canny(num_bloc, 75, 150)

rho = 1              #Distance resolution of the accumulator in pixels.
theta = np.pi/180    #Angle resolution of the accumulator in radians.
threshold = 300       #Only lines that are greater than threshold will be returned.
minLineLength = 50   #Line segments shorter than that are rejected.
maxLineGap = 10     #Maximum allowed gap between points on the same line to link them
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho = rho, theta = theta, threshold = threshold,
                       minLineLength = minLineLength, maxLineGap = maxLineGap)

if lines is not None:
    if lines.size>0 : 
        a,b,c = lines.shape
        for i in range(a):

            x1=lines[i][0][0]
            y1=lines[i][0][1]-5
            x2=lines[i][0][2]
            y2=lines[i][0][3]+5


            area = np.array([[x1, y1], [x2, y1], [x2, y2], [x1, y2]])

        #         cv2.line(table, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #         cv2.rectangle(table, (x1,y1-10 ), (x2,y2+10), (36,255,12), 2)
            cv2.fillPoly(num_bloc, [area], color=(255,255,255))
```

And the output I get (on a subset of the input image) :

[image: Output]

As you can see the vertical dotted lines are still here.

Any advice on how to remove all lines (dotted and full), vertical, horizontal or any angle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use morphological closing operation to close the dotted line.

Try this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

num_bloc = cv2.imread('KZpu3.png',1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(num_bloc, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Remove vertical
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,50))
detected_lines = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detected_lines, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(num_bloc, [c], -1, (33, 227, 253), 2)

edges = cv2.Canny(num_bloc, 75, 150)

rho = 1              #Distance resolution of the accumulator in pixels.
theta = np.pi/180    #Angle resolution of the accumulator in radians.
threshold = 300       #Only lines that are greater than threshold will be returned.
minLineLength = 800   #Line segments shorter than that are rejected.
maxLineGap = 7    #Maximum allowed gap between points on the same line to link them
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho = rho, theta = theta, threshold = threshold,
                       minLineLength = minLineLength, maxLineGap = maxLineGap)

if lines is not None:
    if lines.size>0 : 
        a,b,c = lines.shape
        for i in range(a):

            x1=lines[i][0][0]
            y1=lines[i][0][1]-5
            x2=lines[i][0][2]
            y2=lines[i][0][3]+5


            area = np.array([[x1, y1], [x2, y1], [x2, y2], [x1, y2]])

        #         cv2.line(table, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #         cv2.rectangle(table, (x1,y1-10 ), (x2,y2+10), (36,255,12), 2)
            cv2.fillPoly(num_bloc, [area], color=(33, 227, 253))

width = int(num_bloc.shape[1] * 0.5)
height = int(num_bloc.shape[0] * 0.5)
dim = (width, height)
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(num_bloc, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
resizedthres = cv2.resize(thresh, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imshow('threshold',resizedthres)
cv2.imshow('num_bloc',resized)
```

**Output**

[image]